# How to group every data point with HDBSCAN to some group to have no noise?

Tags: python, clustering, unsupervised-learning, noise, dbscan

**TASK**

- I am clustering products with about 70 dimensions ex.: price, rating 5/5, product tag(cleaning, toy, food, fruits)
- I use HDBSCAN to do it

**GOAL**

- The goal is when users come on our site and I can show similar products to what they viewing.

**QUESTION**

- How to get all data point to be part of a group, so the goal is to not to have any noise?

**CODE**

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=10,#smallest collection of data points you consider a cluster
                            min_samples=1 #LARGER this value -> more points will be declared as NOISE
                           ).fit(data)

color_palette = sns.color_palette('Paired', 2000)
cluster_colors = [color_palette[x] if x >= 0
                  else (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                  for x in clusterer.labels_]
cluster_member_colors = [sns.desaturate(x, p) for x, p in
                         zip(cluster_colors, clusterer.probabilities_)]
plt.scatter(*projection.T, s=20, linewidth=0, c=cluster_member_colors, alpha=0.25)


labels = clusterer.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
```

Comment: The ability to classify observations as "noise" is a key feature of HDBSCAN. I wonder why you want that methods if you don't want noise classifications?

Comment: @Lewian I do want to have hierarchical tree so I can have clusters in multiple LVL ex.: LVL1(food, toys, kitchen equipment), LVL2(bellow the food: beans, rice ...), LVL3(bellow the rice: Jasmin rice, brown rice ... ). I use HDBSCAN because it looks like it can more precisely can define clusters than Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering. Do you recommend Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering instead?

Comment: My first thought looking at your goal is that I'm not sure whether you need clustering at all. If you have a distance, why not just showing a user similar products according to that distance? Why is a clustering needed for this?

Comment: @Lewian you defiantly have a point there and I will probably end up doing that. But the goal would be to bundle products at the end so I need to have LVL2 products (all candies) bundle together with LVL1 Fruits = Easter mix for kids. So the actual situation is a bit more complicated but this is the next phase of the process.

Comment: I'd think that for this you rather need homogeneous clusters; HDBSCAN, Average and Single Linkage may produce quite heterogeneous clusters. You may be better served by Ward's method.